# A command prompt pops up when working with Android (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Okay so Im starting work on android application development. Ive downloaded the newest sdk's. But there seems to be a problem. Whenever i create a project or save a project or edit a project a command prompt pops up

(aapt.exe)

Ive experienced some stuff with android development before and this didnt happen before. Is there a way i can put android development into "Silent" mode while working as it gets somewhat annyoing.

Thanks

Comment: What the command prompt says?PS:Welcome to SO

Comment: Theres nothing desplayed P.S. Thanks for welcoming me to SO. :) Ive been folowing the site for a very long time now i just decided to register recently

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of the command prompt?

Comment: Hi codemonkey, thanks for the reply unfortunately I cant attach anything to stackoverflow as of yet because i need "10 points" i believe. im not at home right now as im out on avacation When i get home ill place a screenshot somewhere and then copy the link here.

Answer (score 0):

AAPT is a tool that processes the ressources of your app:

> The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML files for your Activities, and compiles them. An R.java is also produced so you can reference your resources from your Java code.

So I think that you did some errors in your ressources or xml files. Eclipse has problems to detect and show these kind of errors. You should check your xml files.
There are also some links on StackOverflow:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829718/issue-with-aapt-exe) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047844/aapt-exe-has-stopped-working-in-eclipse-4-3-kepler-sdk-22-3-api-level-19) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663749/aapt-exe-has-stopped-working)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but, this isnt quite my question. There is no problem in the code, its just that a command prompt pops up when i try to compile, save or edit the code.

it isnt hindering me from developing. But it gets really annoying at times.