# Android. Process 'command > '....aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero > exit value 1

Tags: android, drawable

Added 25 png files to drawable folder. When I try to run app, I am getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'D:\ANDROID\sdk\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

R is shown as error:

> Cannot resolve symbol R

I tried to **Project->Clear Project**, but no effect. But when delete those png files, everything working correctly. The problem is here, I need to use those png files in my application.

How to solve this problem?

PNG files

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the exact name with extension you used in for png files?

Comment: @WaqarKhan, Pasted list of files

Comment: There is a SO Thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26452895/3117296) that addresses the same issue. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, all was because I have png file named: 'try.png'. Try to rename this file.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we got same issue. But We changed **from JPG image to PNG image**, than it is working perfectly.