# Error:Execution failed for task :app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android-Studio.

When i tried to compile the project i got error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> at index 4
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.user.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Any suggestion please?thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any of these solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Comment: sure, but it isn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change:

This:
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

To:
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

The newer buildTools sometimes have some bugs

Comment: also higher than 21.0.1? like 21.0.2?

Comment: yeah..i'm look at this link before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Comment: Also try to change targetSDK and CompileSDK and if that doesnt work try to remove parse for a moment

Comment: hi, i tried to remove 'parse' and still same problem

Comment: And this?
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
To:
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.0'

Comment: now i got this error: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-21' in: C:\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue today. This is how I fixed it:

1. Check to see that the latest 23.0.3 build tool was installed. In my case (shown below), I noticed it wasn't installed:
   [image: Install the 23.0.3 SDK Build-tools]
2. Then, in my app level build.gradle, I changed this:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
   ```

   to

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
   ```

Hopefully this helps anyone encountering this issue recently.