# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, xml, gradle

In Android Studio I have this error when I update Android SDK Tools to version 25:

[image]

I tried to modify SDK version in gradle build to 21 to execute my app but I have this error. Really I don't why this happens.
This is my `build.gradle` file:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Paste the content of your project level and app level gradle files

Comment: Fixed image positioning

Comment: i pasted my gradle file it's in the picture, and my peject level API is 25 it's that enough

Comment: Maybe this response can fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/31203627/2666042

Comment: Hey , @zakaria Did you fixed that ? How?

Comment: @bdevloper i clean my project and invalidate cache and restart in menu file that fixed the problem for me,  you can try that !

Comment: Yes I do that more than 20 times but didn't help. And I got this error in each and every project (new created and old once also). Thanks for reply if u have some other solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your build tools, and the error will be fixed automatically.

Comment: Do you mean upgrade Gradle? Or the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue before seeing this post i solved it by exiting android studio and running it with administrative privilege

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this after adding google maps. It turned out being a missing key reference

```
Error:(45) resource string/google_maps_key (aka com.your.package:string/google_maps_key) not found.
Error:(45) error: resource string/google_maps_key (aka com.your.package:string/google_maps_key) not found.
android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

In the manifest. Which needed to be added in the build.gradle script as showin in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker.  After adding the following to `build.gradle`

```
  resValue "string", "google_maps_key",
          (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
```

The `aapt` error went away.