# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task in Intellij 2017 running on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2017 Ultimate version in Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I have created my first Android application here and it gives me this error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
      > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I am using java version 1.8.0_131 and Android SDK API 24.

Java projects work properly and I used the same method of creating the Android Application in Windows 7 and it works properly.

I will be thankful, if you can help me in this matter.

Comment: [Did you google the error message?](https://www.google.com/#q=+com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:+Failed+to+execute+aapt). If so, what specifically did you try and what were the results? If none of the search results were helpful, what is different about your current situation?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio