# Getting error after importing project to android studio

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I'm getting this error when trying to run the project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

My gradle:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {

            repositories {
                maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.trynagrub.trynagrub"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
        compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'org.zakariya.stickyheaders:stickyheaders:0.7.6'
        compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
        compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.0.3'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.6'
        compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.3'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
        compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.snatik:storage:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.github.tamir7.contacts:contacts:1.1.7'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have this project on two computers, one which I wrote the code on and one that I sent the code to. The project is built fine on the first computer but from some reason it doesn't work on second one.

I think it has something to do with the gradle version, I updated Android studio version and the gradle version...
Please help...

Also: The R resources cannot be resolved which means resources linking failed too.

Answer (score 0):

your intuition is correct! possibly due to the grade version line:

> For me it helped to change the version of buildTools to:
>
> buildToolsVersion "21.0.1" You will find this setting inside the file
>   app/build.gradle.

source:
[Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio)

edit:
if you updated to android studio 3.0 I also have the warning about SDK build tools version. Might need to change the version to "21.0.2" instead.