# How to solve to this Error ??? when i trying to cordova build apk?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

when i'm trying to build apk **ionic cordova build android** use this cmd. i'll  get following this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt**

and i'm using

**cordova requirements**

Requirements check results for android:

> Java JDK: installed 1.8.0 Android SDK: installed true Android target:
>   installed android-P,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,Google
>   Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23,Google Inc.:Google
>   APIs:23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android
>   Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4\bin\gradle
>
> Requirements check results for browser: Check failed for browser due
>   to Failed to check requirements for browser platform. check_reqs
>   module is missing for platform. Skipping it...

**ionic info**

cli packages: (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules)

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.1.0
```

System:

```
Node              : v6.11.3
npm               : 3.10.10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it doing a `./gradlew clean build` ! Give it a try and if that doesn't work, try `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` after and you should be good to go.

Copied from [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Karthik,.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Karthik,.

          I tried './gradlew --refresh-dependencies' this one..But again i get this same Error..
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: make sure you have given correct build tools version in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

If above solution is not helpful then first check aapt is installed or not?

aapt is 32 bit so will not execute on a 64 bit box until 32 bit architecture is enabled

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures  #  if prints nothing then below is fix

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  #  add a 32 bit architecture to box

sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6

sudo apt-get install -y lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev
```

it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

one signal plugin is not supported to the version..i'll remove that plugin and add the lower version..It's worked for me..
1.**cordova plugin rm onesignal-cordova-plugin**
2.add to manually **package.json**

```
dependencies
{
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.3.2"
}
```

and

```
plugins {
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
}
```

3.**npm install**
4.**ionic cordova build android**

Thanks Guys ,

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have problems with android [support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/). There is a new version for android - P. You can download [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) and set support android version, which is your android app sdk 
target version.