# Android Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, aapt

When I try to build my project I allways get this error:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I've tried to disable instant run but it didn't work for me. Also tried to downgrade Buildtools to 21.0.1 like the solution here:
[Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio?answertab=active#tab-top)

Anyone an idea?