# When build in android studio i get error :app:processDebugResources

Tags: android

When I run Build - rebuild project I get the following error 
I have tryed many sollution but nothing works..

What went wrong:

the error build code:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/appiconlarge () not found.","sources":[{"file":"/home/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar/a9a8f29f5baeae5b590388a64347d1e6/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1362,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":99385,"endLine":1403,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":102566}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processDebugResources
error: failed linking references.
:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**Build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain:"@string/com_auth0_domain"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:lock:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: update to latest builToolVersion in build.gradle

Comment: What build tools version gradle are you using? What OS are you working on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio)

Comment: Would you please update build.gradle file with your question.

Comment: i use ubuntu 16.04 android-studio version 3.1.4
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Comment: try checking your resource files.

Comment: Would you please post the full error message also?

Comment: For AAPT2 Error refer this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988596/3974530

Comment: something wrong with your resource files

Comment: @Niklas hope you got the answer. Please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is

> resource drawable/appiconlarge not found

Please check the `drawable/appiconlarge` file exists or not. If not please add `appiconlarge` image on the `drawable` directory.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Consider doing this, not sure it would remove the error but it helped in my case.

```
android.enableAapt2=true
```