# React Native Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: react-native

This problem has been stated When I add firebase

This problem happen when react-native run-android

I tried to ./grandlew clean and all solitons but still continues.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
```

Full Error;

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: You did run ./gradlew clean inside ./android path only right?

Comment: yes , after come back project path and run react-native run-android and same problem

Comment: buildToolsVersion "21.0.1" try with this as mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Comment: still same error

Comment: Have you gone through the above link which I have shared because the issue has been resolved in many answers in that you may find one useful among them