# Gradle error after updating android studio and flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I updated flutter and android studio and cannot get the emulator to load the project. The error is:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
>     C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:69: AAPT: error: resource xml/file_provider_path (aka com.lightbridge.lbconnect:xml/file_provider_path) not found.

I imported the project to Android Studio and ran the Android X refactor and it still doesnt work. My SDK version is set to 28 and Ive tried everything to fix it. The FILE_PROVIDER_PATH is not in my manifest file but it never has been.

Here is a list of my plugins but like I said it loaded fine in the emulator yesterday:

dev_dependencies:

font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1

http: ^0.12.0

intl: ^0.15.7

device_calendar: ^0.0.7

url_launcher: ^5.0.1

swipedetector: ^1.2.0

contacts_service: ^0.2.1

agora_rtc_engine: 0.9.4

permission_handler: ^3.0.0

validators: ^2.0.0

path_provider: ^1.1.0

share_extend: ^1.0.9

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Comment: buildToolsVersion doesnt exist as a setting in my flutter project

Comment: That's because is inside your build.gradle file inside the Android project of Flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449346/3743245

add that value is necessary