# Android Studio: Build failed with every project

Tags: android-studio

I have just started to use android studio, so I don't have much experience, and I'm getting some errors when I try to run any project, even the most simple one like Hello World. I've been trying to find the cause but I can't find it.
The errors I get is this:

```
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Failed to transform artifact 'customview.aar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
  > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7462826920a444bc012a531aa0e2732f\customview-1.0.0.
     > C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7462826920a444bc012a531aa0e2732f\customview-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

    > Failed to transform artifact 'customview.aar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
  > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7462826920a444bc012a531aa0e2732f\customview-1.0.0.
     > C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7462826920a444bc012a531aa0e2732f\customview-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
       > Failed to transform artifact 'interpolator.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
  > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aff4cda642e9b4135c366a5a833fc1b9\interpolator-1.0.0.
     > C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aff4cda642e9b4135c366a5a833fc1b9\interpolator-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

       > Failed to transform artifact 'core-runtime.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
  > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\271101febb7091720500cb88bb508af9\core-runtime-2.0.0.
     > C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\271101febb7091720500cb88bb508af9\core-runtime-2.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

       > Failed to transform artifact 'core-runtime.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
  > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\271101febb7091720500cb88bb508af9\core-runtime-2.0.0.
     > C:\Users\alma_\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\271101febb7091720500cb88bb508af9\core-runtime-2.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Can anyone give some advise about my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio)

Comment: Hello Mordakay, did you find solution for that. I'm having the same issue :|

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was trying to add `aar` file to my project according to producent's user manual. Unfortunately gradle was throwing this error and I couldn't find the solution.

This, what I've done to make it running, was adding reference by the Android Studio Wizard.

Go to `File -> ProjectStructure`. Click on `Modules` on left side, then `+` icon in `Modules` section. Choose `Import .JAR/.AAR Package`. Android Studio will create some gradle files and directory for your `aar` file. Then go to `Dependencies` (in Project Structure window, right below `Modules` on the left side) and click on your master project (probably `app`), then in `Declared Dependencies` (it's window on the right side) click on `+` icon and add your AAR file to the master project.

The Android Studio structure for importing AAR file is not the same like declared by software producer (`implementation fileTree(include: ['xxx.aar'], dir: 'libs'`) but is working.