# Getting Error while Running Flutter App On Android (Android X) Incompatibility

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, incompatibility, android-jetifier

I have been getting this error while running my app on android due to android X incompatibility. I am unable to fix this issue even after enabling `multiDex true`. Please help

[image]

Comment: May be check this answer on **stackoverflow**, [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20737200/9949983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my `compileSDK` to `30` and changed `targetSDKVersion` to `30` as well and changed `minSDKVersion` to `21` in my app level build.gradle and it started to work for me. And I also changed from `classpath'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` to `classpath'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'` in my android build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

May be check this answer on **StackOverflow**, [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20737200/9949983)

And also don't forget to clean the flutter project when you start after changing the configuration

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/30303374/11120544 this answer from the above thread linked by @AbdelTilahun ?

Comment: @Apps247 Yes I tried that as well but same error again.