# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:E:\flutter projects2\loca_social\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:48: AAPT: error: 'AIzaSyBN3CtvuzePaqObywmztxAmzmAuf9zGqtA' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 1s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: You can find its solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

With only this error given, there could be a lot of possible causes. But this might be leaning to AndroidX incompatibility. If you've recently upgraded an old Flutter project that has yet to migrate to AndroidX, you can follow this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration).

Make sure that you're also using up-to-date versions of the plugins that you're using, then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the indexes.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUhKl.png)

You don't need this item, delete it

Comment: Please do not include images of code inside your answer.