# fix Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, runtime-error

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6054: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_500) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6055: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6058: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6059: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6054: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_500) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6055: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6058: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6059: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:12: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:13: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:16: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:17: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:12: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:13: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:16: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:17: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
> error: failed linking references.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:348)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:244)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:124)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:102)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6054: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_500) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6055: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6058: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6059: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6054: error: resource color/purple_500 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_500) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6055: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6058: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml:6059: error: resource color/teal_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:12: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:13: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:16: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:17: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:12: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:13: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/purple_700) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:16: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:17: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.buglyapp:color/teal_200) not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:33)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:188)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:124)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$leasingAapt2Daemon$1.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:199)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.link(PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.kt:51)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:74)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:914)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.access$invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:761)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:388)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
  at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
  at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:212)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
  ... 2 more
  Suppressed: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to get absolute path from com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml
  because com.example.buglyapp-mergeDebugResources-27 is not key in sourceSetPathMap.
  at com.android.ide.common.resources.RelativeResourceUtils$relativeResourcePathToAbsolutePath$1.invoke(RelativeResourceUtils.kt:91)
  at com.android.ide.common.resources.RelativeResourceUtils$relativeResourcePathToAbsolutePath$1.invoke(RelativeResourceUtils.kt:68)
  at com.android.ide.common.resources.RelativeResourceUtils.relativeResourcePathToAbsolutePath(RelativeResourceUtils.kt:61)
  at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.aapt.Aapt2ErrorParser$MessageParser.parse(Aapt2ErrorParser.kt:124)
  at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.aapt.Aapt2ErrorParser.parse(Aapt2ErrorParser.kt:99)
  at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.aapt.Aapt2OutputParser.parse(Aapt2OutputParser.java:56)
  at com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:84)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:217)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:133)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:76)
  at

Comment: Looks like here is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio Cheers!

Comment: Please take a look to thissolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio