# Error while using physical device in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> BUILD FAILED in 6s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

it was working when i was using chrome simulator but not on phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.